# visual studio не компилирует проект angular 2

Tags: visual-studio, angular2

Пытаюсь запустить "quickstart angular 2" посредством visual studio и получаю кучу ошибок типа:
Cannot find name 'Map'.
Cannot find name 'Promise
при этом если делать просто с помощью npm start, все нормально работает.
Буду благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это дело не в студии ,а в том что у вас не установлены typings.

```
npm typings intall
```